# Sweetalert2 won't close

Tags: aurelia, sweetalert, sweetalert2

using

- aurelia-cli - 0.30.1
- sweetalert2 - 6.6.5
- typescript - 2.3.3
- latest browsers (FF, Chrome, IE, Opera)

ts code

```
public showHelp() {
    swal('Test').then((out) => {
      console.log(out);
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

alert displays with no problems, but clicking on confirm button does not dismis the alert. alert also won't dismiss on outside click. pressing ESC or ENTER works fine.
no errors throw ...

any idea why this will not accept click?

I have put breakpoints on these

```
// Mouse interactions
var onButtonEvent = function onButtonEvent(event) {

// Closing modal by close button
getCloseButton().onclick = function () {

// Closing modal by overlay click
container.onclick = function (e) {
```

in swal source, but they never get hit...

also tried setting target to something else than `body`, with the same result.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an Aurelia problem. You may get better answers by searching issues in the library repo.

Comment: I agree, but I have no idea what is causing it or how to debug it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and apparently this is what was giving me the problem:

```
.swal2-container:not(.swal2-in) {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Just comment that line or change **none** to **all** (Although I don't know yet if it breaks anything else)

I'm using:

- [paper-dashboard](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-dashboard-angular) (free angular2 version) - 1.0.0
- angular.cli - 1.1.1
- sweetalert2 - 6.6.6
- typescript - 2.3.3
- latest browsers (same)

Comment: you're right! just to add to this, the problem is in file material-dashboard.css or in plugins\_sweetalert2.scss.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce what you're experiencing. Using sweetalert2 v6.6.6 (oh dear), the alert displays and hides properly on all scenarios you mention: the [OK] button, clicking outside the alert dialog and the keyboard modifiers.

I'm using the configuration below. You're probably already aware, but please do note that I'm explicitly including the css file in the aurelia.json and referencing it in the app.html view.

Here is the full app:

**aurelia.json**

```
{
    "name": "sweetalert2",
    "path": "../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist",
    "main": "sweetalert2",
    "resources": [
      "sweetalert2.css"
    ]
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2';

export class App {
  attached() {
    this.showHelp();
  }

  public showHelp() {
    swal('Test').then((out) => {
      console.log(out);
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="sweetalert2/sweetalert2.css"></require>
</template>
```

Comment: you're right there. I have created new test project and the clik works fine, but not in my current project. I will have to go dependecy after dependency to find out what is going on ...